# SQL - Create a query that shows the users that logged in the most in a certain time span

Tags: sql

My table looks like that

| timestamp | userid |
| --- | --- |
| date | user1 |
| date | user2 |
| date | user1 |
| date | user3 |
| date | user1 |
| date | user2 |

I simply want to create an sql state that selects all users and sorts them by how many times they did a login in a certain period of time.

I made it to distinct select the users, but not more...

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid 
FROM mytable 
WHERE timestamp >= '2021-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2021-01-02';
```

Comment: tag your database as well.

Comment: You probably want `timestamp < '2021-01-03'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way:

```
  select userid,count(*) loginattempt
  from mytable 
  where timestamp >= '2021-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2021-01-02';
  group by userid
  order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we use Group by like below?

```
select count(*), userid FROM mytable WHERE timestamp >= '2021-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2021-01-02' group by userid;
```